# alternative rows on custom adapter

Tags: android

I was following [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) tutorial.

I got the custom adapter code here:

```
LazyAdapter.java
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList&lt;HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;&gt; data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList&lt;HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;&gt; d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
        TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
        TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

        HashMap&lt;String, String&gt; song = new HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;();
        song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
        artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));
        duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

This will give me an out put of n number of list items with same design ( as  vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null); )

I need some alternate things. Like I will define another type of list_row, and I need it randomly. How to achieve this?

Comment: Randomly or alternate?

Comment: anything , with another layout. My aim is that, 1st item will be a photo, 2nd item will have 2 photos and a text.. etc. So how to bring another layout between this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705832/listview-with-different-layout-inflation-for-each-row/15706073#15706073. check this link and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370525/listview-adapter-with-arbitrary-number-of-row-types-dont-know-the-number-of-di/17370772#17370772

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to having different type of rows in `ListView` is to override two methods in `BaseAdapter` - [`getViewTypeCount`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) and [`getItemViewType(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29). This requires that for any given position, you can determine what the view type is.

This tutorial on [Handling ListViews with Multiple Row Types](http://logc.at/2011/10/10/handling-listviews-with-multiple-row-types/) should get you started.