# listview with different view layouts

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview with different rows with different layout.

layout1.xml

```
<LinearLayout
android:height="wrap_content"
android:width="fill_parent">

<TextView
android:height="wrap_content"
android:width="wrap_content"
android:text="One" 
android="@+id/one"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

layout2.xml

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:width="fill_parent">

    <TextView
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:width="wrap_content"
    android:text="One"
    android="@+id/one" />

 <TextView
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Two"
    android="@+id/one" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

> Since the adapter recycles all of its views, how will it know if
>   layout1 is recycled. If layout1 is recycled, convertView is not null,
>   and I try to find textview2. Should this throw null pointer?
>
> Assume convertView is always recycled and no need to inflate view. So,
>   layout1 is recycled, but the below code is expecting layout2 for the
>   position.

in the getView(),

```
@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                      ViewGroup parent) {
         //A method to tell if layout1 or layout2 should be inflated based on the position
         boolean inflateOne = inflateLayoutOne(position);

   if(convertView == null){


      if(inflateOne)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, null);
      else
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2, null);
    }

    if(inflateOne){
     TextView tv1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.one);
     tv1.setText("Hello one");
    }
    else{
     TextView tv1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.one);
     tv1.setText("Hello one");
     TextView tv2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.two);
     tv1.setText("Hello Two");.

return convertView;

  }
```

Comment: My question is to understand, how does the listview know which type it is, while getting the recycled view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works. see this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing it wrong. If you want to have different kind of rows, you have to override `getViewTypeCount` and `getViewItemType`. Both return an int value. getView will receive a number of null convertView equals to the value you return in `getViewTypeCount`. You should use `getViewItemType` to distinguish between the different view

Answer (score 0):

To tell which layout the convertView is returning, you should be able to just compare the ids.

```
if (convertView.getId() == R.layout.layout1){
    //set data for layout 1
}else if(convertView.getId() == R.layout.layout1){
    //set data for layout 1
}
```

Comment: Exactly, but this is not done on any of the reference articles, or here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/15706073/563306

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter must override getItemViewType(int position). From the docs:

> Returns: An integer representing the type of View. Two views should
>   share the same type if one can be converted to the other in
>   getView(int, View, ViewGroup). Note: Integers must be in the range 0
>   to getViewTypeCount() - 1. IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE can also be
>   returned.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)