# ClassCastException don't know where though

Tags: java, android

Here is my logcat

```
08-05 09:05:59.833  24812-24812/com.Pi110.KGHS E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
        at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1163)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:868)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2267)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1074)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2462)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4558)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am not even working with a listview in my layout so I have no idea where I am getting this error. Any help would be great. It doesn't occur in api 22 but so far in older android versions.

It seems to have occured after I added this code.

```
 @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rss_item, parent, false);
  holder = new ViewHolder();
     if ((position % k) == 0) {
            if (convertView instanceof AdView) {
                return convertView;
            } else {


                holder.mAdView = (AdView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adView);


                return holder.mAdView;
            }}
        else {
         convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rss_item, parent, false);
            holder.itemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
            holder.itemTitle.setTypeface(face);
            holder.itemTitle1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            holder.itemTitle2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            Typeface face1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
            holder.itemTitle1.setTypeface(face1);
         holder.itemTitle2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
  EventItem item = itemList.get(position);
    holder.itemTitle.setText(item.getTitle());

   holder.itemTitle1.setText(item.getDate());
  holder.itemTitle2.setText(item.getCategories());
  if (item.getIcon()!= 1){
  holder.image.setImageResource(item.getIcon());}
  return convertView;
}
```

Here is that layout

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id= "@+id/layout"
android:background= "@drawable/transition"
android:padding="8dp"
>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="20sp"
   android:ellipsize="end"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:singleLine="true"
   android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
   android:textColor="#ff000000"
   android:paddingTop="5dp"
   android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#ff8d8d8d"
    android:paddingRight= "10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView"
    android:textColor="#ff8d8d8d"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:paddingRight= "10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/customicon"/>
```

yup, the error is there. I removed basically all lines except for the convertView return statement and it was fine?!!!!!??????

My code seems fine... I'm gonna try to clean it again thanks all.

Comment: We need to see some code to help with this.

Comment: Did you try cleaning and rebuilding the app?

Comment: Misstype in your code ? `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams`. Check if you are casting in your code `LayoutParams` but from different classes `RelativeLayout` and `AbsListView`.

Comment: If you need to inflate different layouts check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705832/listview-with-different-layout-inflation-for-each-row.  I am not sure what your trying to do

Comment: Just hint. Do not load your typefaces in every getView(). Set it once and use TypefaceHelper with case.

Comment: 'I am not even working with a listview in my layout' if you are not working with listview then why you are using adapter?

Comment: It is for a special library type of listview

Comment: Is it possible that wherever that layout gets put into the listview is where it is going wrong?

Comment: Its just odd that the apis aren't consistent

Comment: I might have figured it out it seems like it might be because of jazzylistview

Comment: Maybe not never mind

Answer (score 3):

Replace first line of getView() method:

```
convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.rss_item, null);
```

To

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rss_item, parent, false);
```

Problem is list view assumes that getView() method will return a view that belongs to `AbsListView` parent view. But your code is returning a view whose parent is `RelativeLayout.

Comment: Can you edit your code with new one in you question?

Comment: I did what you said to do

Comment: I think problem is return holder.mAdView; line in else block. Its parent is relative layout not abslistadapter.

Comment: From your code it looks like you are trying to show addView at every kth position. So you need to make another layout that will hold only addView and inflate this layout and return.

Comment: Thanks changing the return statement to convertview fixed it.... weird bug though